# Intergrating Stripe with HubSpot

Tags: stripe-payments, hubspot

I'm trying to set up a form of payment on HubSpot. My client selected stripe before I was on board and I've been spending backend of last week and this morning trying to integrate the two.

I've come to realise that HubSpot doesn't support server-side languages making it impossible to setup stripe on its own. I was also told that Zapier was going to make the integration between form submission to database for us. After a few emails with Zapier, I was told that isn't what their service does.

I've done a lot of searching on google but haven't found anything very fruitful. I was hoping someone with more experience in HubSpot would be able to direct me to a solution to set up Stripe or another product that would be useful to applying a payment form submission on HubSpot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you would need a plugin developed for HubSpot that built out a Stripe payment flow.  There is no way to accept payments through Stripe that doesn't use a server-side language.  You *may* be able to tie into a third-party service like CommencePayments (https://commencepayments.com/), but I'm not sure even that would work.

Comment: I figured as much after not seeing anything on a google search. I appreciate you confirming for me. I'll look into commencePayments.